# Repetição For Erro Function

Tags: php

Estou com um erro dentro de uma laço for. O Erro da-me para a linha da Function.

```
$Valor = "SELECT max(id) FROM tb_empresa";
For ($contatador = 0; $contador = $Valor; $contador++){

//Código 

function estaParaExpirar($data, $dias=10) {
if (!strtotime($data) || empty($data)) return false;
return(strtotime($data) < strtotime("+".$dias. "days") );
}
```

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare estaParaExpirar()

Comment: Ok, vamos por partes: $contatador está escrito errado. É $contador, e $contador = $Valor deve ser $contador == $Valor. Se a função estaParaExpirar() tiver o seu escopo dentro do laço, recomendo que coloque fora e use apenas a chamada para ela dentro do for.

Comment: Só para explicar o que o @Dalton citou: `$contador = 0` você atribui um valor ao contador; `$contador == 0` verifica uma igualdade 'simples' onde 0(integer) é igual a '0'(string); `$contador === 0` verifica uma igualdade exata em ralação ao tipo onde 0(integer) é diferente de '0'(string)

Comment: Sobre a questão, você **NÃO** pode declara mais de uma função com o mesmo nome `Cannot redeclare`. Qual seria a lógica em ter 2 funções idênticas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dá erro porque definiu a função estaParaExpirar dentro de um loop, o que faz que a cada ciclo do loop e função seja declarada e uma função só pode ser declarada uma vez dentro do seu escopo. Aqui tem duas opções: declara a função fora do loop e chama dentro do loop , ou retira a declaração de função e executa o código da função dentro do loop

```
$Valor = "SELECT max(id) FROM tb_empresa";
For ($contatador = 0; $contador == $Valor; $contador++){

//Código 

if (!strtotime($data) || empty($data)) 
    return  false;

return (strtotime($data) < strtotime("+".$dias. "days") );


}
```

Comment: O seu `return` vai retornar `TRUE|FALSE`, mas qual é o proposito de um return dentro de um for fora de um escopo de função?

Comment: A minha base é o código que foi apresentado. O proposito do return dentro do "for" é interromper o script quando determinada condição for alcançada e retornar esse valor. Note que eu disse interromper o "script". Não sei se é esse o proposito, apenas não alterei muito o que foi apresentado

Comment: Veja o controle [break](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php).

Comment: O controle break interrompe o ciclo mas não para o script, nem devolve qualquer resultado. Também pode usar o continue se desejar saltar qualquer interação. Depende do que quiser fazer. Eu, neste exemplo, optei por fazer com que o script devolvesse um resultado. Também podia ter optado atribuir esse resultado a uma variável.

Comment: `devolvesse um resultado`. Devolve o resultado para lugar nenhum, pois nenhuma variável vai atribuir o valor do for.

Comment: Tanto um script como uma função podem devolver um valor. O script devolve um valor para o cliente, que neste caso, pode ser uma requisição ajax.

Comment: Estou no cel mas vou comentar. 
Request para  ajax é echo e nao return, alem do mais, a questao nao faz nenhuma referencia a javascript

Comment: Estava justamente testando isso, usar o return no escopo global interrompe a execução do script mas não retorna o valor de `return` para o cliente, logo não pode ser obtido como resultado em uma requisição ajax, para isso é preciso usar `echo` seguido de `exit` ou diretamente `exit(resultado)`

Comment: Certo, eu não foi tão preciso quanto deveria ser. A ideia inicial era explicar o conceito e não mudar muito o código. O que entendi da pergunta era que quando existisse determinada condição parar o script e fazer qualquer coisa com essa condição. Assumi que podeira ser o método de um objeto e que esse método retornasse um valor. Estamos a lidar com conceitos, coisas abstratas. Realmente o return dentro de um escopo global normalmente não imprime nada.